# form submission error html & php

Tags: php, ajax, html

I am buidling a php contact form with ajax validation. While I submit the contact form I get error message "spammer" which is not supposed to.

Below is my code html & php code.

Index.php

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="mailer.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your email message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lct9zUUAAAAABpj9vwKX9B7x_AH8s9gwJzFW1sB"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="formresult">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Mailer.php

```
  <?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }

    //Validate the data
    if (empty($name) OR empty($phone) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($message) OR empty($captcha)) {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span> <strong>Please fill all the form inputs and check the captcha to submit.</strong>";
      exit;
    }

    //recipient email address.
    $recipient = "abc@abc.com";
    $subject = "New message from $name";

    //email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
    //email headers
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR_SECRATE_KEY&amp;response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);

    if($decoded_response['success'] == true){
      // Send the email.
      if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span> <strong>Thank You! Your message has been sent.</strong>";
      } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Your message cannot be sent";
      }
    } else {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo 'spammer!';
    }
  }
  ?>
```

When I submit the form I get a error message 'spammer' and even mail does not get through.

I know there is some mistake in logic but i cannot figure it out.

Anyone please help me in this. Thank you.

Comment: your `if else` statement is wrong. You can't have two `else`

Comment: You need to properly identify how to label someone as "spammer"

Comment: @hungrykoala I'm not seeing that problem.

Comment: @Delte either your recaptcha is not working properly, or the response is not what you expected. Check what is actually coming back in $reponse.

Comment: I am getting response & recaptcha is working fine too. something else which can help me?

Comment: that's not what I said. I didn't say you weren't getting a response, I asked you to check whether the response is _what you expected_. Clearly, based on your description that "spammer" is always returned, then `if($decoded_response['success'] == true){` must never be true, so it follows from there that $repsonse doesn't have a "success" property, or it isn't set to true. That's the first bit of info we need.

Comment: Wohaaaaa this resolve the issue. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code:

```
if($decoded_response['success'] == true){
```

Must be evaluating to false, and executing the else part of that statement. Displaying the spammer message.

Check the decoded contents returned from the recaptcha url, that you assign to the $decoded_response variable.

```
print_r($decoded_response); // should show the whole contents
```

Comment: I worked on as you have suggested & booom that resolved to help me an issue. Cheers!

Comment: @Delte glad I could help. Please upvote my answer or mark it as the correct answer. Happy coding!